# Python/wxPython + Py2Exe + Inno Setup Compiler: “Errno 13: Permission denied…” error

Tags: wxpython, inno-setup

Good day,
I created a desktop application using wxPython + Py2Exe + Inno Setup Compiler on window 32-bit OS. Everything works fine as expected.
After distributing the application to new users on windows 32-bit and 64-bit, they install the installer successfully, but upon launching the application at some point the app crashes and display a dialog with “Errno 13: Permission denied…” see the snap shut of the error message below;

[image: Errno 13, help me please...]

What could have caused this on their PC and not mine? It never crashed on my PC. How can I amend this error? Bulk of the PC I have tested the application reported this error.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many things worth considering here.

1. Are you in an environment that uses User Account Control?
   1a. If so, does running as an admin work?  See [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExcludingDlls) for info about excluding dlls.
   1b. Possible DLL's to exclude (from my setup.py which successfully deploys wx):

   `['w9xpopen.exe', 'MSVCP90.dll', 'mswsock.dll', 'powrprof.dll', 'MPR.dll', 'MSVCR100.dll', 'mfc90.dll']`
2. It's probably worth taking control of your stdout and stderr files (so that you can debug exceptions).  Do this early in your program's execution.  That might look something like this:

   `if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
     sys.stderr = open(r'c:\path\to\writable\file', 'w')
     sys.stdout = open(r'c:\path\to\another\file', 'w')`
3. If you're currently passing your script name to `setup` in the windows argument, try passing it in the console argument instead.  When run from a command prompt you may be able to see exceptions and tracebacks.

Comment: I will try all your suggestions and see what happens.